# If server request method post echo html doesent work

Tags: php, html, post, methods

When the server detect a post method echo the html. Why doesent work?

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
echo '<b>ciao</b>';
}
```

Comment: Risposta: If your form doesn't contain a POST method, then there you go amico mio. - I.e. `method="post"`

Comment: My form contain method="post"

Comment: You will need to show your full code then and make sure your file is `.php` extension.

Comment: What aeeror are you getting?

Comment: C&P this snippet in your code: ` <?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
 ?>`

Comment: You could try all single quotes `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')` but I doubt that would make any difference. Make sure you also have an input submit type button and not just a button. Again, show FULL code. Your question risks in getting closed. Edit: too late.

Comment: Next time, post your full code. This question could have easily been answered within 30 seconds. You more than likely didn't have an input submit type. Just a bad question. Read this => http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Fred-ii- it could easily been answered in 30 sec. from you! :D I got it in 3 min's :D

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks. Your answer definitely leaves the guesswork **out** of everything. +1 hard to go wrong with that ;)

Comment: Im sorry, this is my first question on stackoverflow. :(

Comment: @user3578022 If you want to buy a good pair of shoes while making sure they are comfortable and won't hurt your feet, you need to tell the shoe salesperson what your shoe size is, otherwise he/she won't know what to give you. ;) same thing goes for questions. buongiorno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

(If you press the `GET` button you should get `"From Method GET"` and if you press the `POST` button you should get `"From Method POST"`)

But you have to submit the form otherwise the Server will not react! You also have to make sure your file ends with `.php` and is saved in the webserver.

Also you should have a webserver with PHP!

PHP:

```
<?php

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
        echo '<b>From Method POST</b>';
    } elseif($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET"){
        echo '<b>From Method GET</b>';
    }    

?>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton1" value="POST">
</form>

<form action="" method="get">
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton2" value="GET">
</form>
```

BTW for error messages use:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
?>
```

Comment: @user3578022 your welcome :D have a nice day! (hint for the next question!: specify your question as much as possible and show the relevant code so that we see what your problem is!)